# ftp_chmod() & ftp_site() not working on localhost with zFTP Server

Tags: php, ftp, localhost, chmod

I've been stuck on this for hours now.

Trying to CHMOD files with PHP by running the following code on http://localhost.

```
ftp_chmod($conn_id, "0644", $file);
ftp_site($conn_id, "CHMOD 0644 ".$file);
```

but neither will work. Keep getting these errors:

> Warning: ftp_chmod(): Invalid SITE command. in C:\Users\Albert\Web Design\localhost\httpdocs\admin\global\php.php on line 226 could not chmod sitemap.xml
>
> Warning: ftp_site(): Invalid SITE command. in C:\Users\Albert\Web Design\localhost\httpdocs\admin\global\php.php on line 232 could not chmod sitemap.xml

On the production server (LIVE), however, they run fine. I'm obviously missing something here. I'm assuming this has something to do with the settings in either my php.ini file or my locally installed FTP server which is zFTP.

I've exhausted myself searching google and don't know where else to turn. Any ideas?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Its windows no need chmod there, thats why its not working on our local version.

Comment: DUUUH!!!! I wish I would've known this 2 hours ago. Thanks man for clearing that up. I'm obviously a retard!

Comment: 2 hours not much, so do i solved your problem?